# Determine the load context of an assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

Given a loaded `Assembly` is there a way (in code) to determine which of the 3 load contexts it was loaded into (default **Load**, **LoadFrom,** or **Neither**)?

In [Suzanne Cook's "Choosing a Binding Context"](https://web.archive.org/web/20190124235454/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context/) article, there are some disadvantages that occur when an assembly is loaded into the **LoadFrom**.  In particular, my library uses deserialization and encounters an `InvalidCastException` when loaded into the **LoadFrom** context.

Currently my library fails very late (it fails when it executes the problematic deserialization code--see [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255892/how-to-reproduce-invalidcastexception-when-binding-to-an-assembly-in-the-loadfro)).  I'd like to make it fail much earlier in these circumstances by detecting the context it is loaded into and throwing an exception if it is not loaded into the default **Load** context.

Comment: IMO one (not very elegant) solution would be to subclass Assembly, rewrite the Load methods and add custom flags when one of the methods is used.

Comment: @pasty The Load method that is used doesn't necessarily result in the assembly being loaded into a particular context.  I.e. Calling Assembly.Load does not always cause the assembly to be loaded in the default Load context.  Furthermore, I am not in control of the code loading the assembly.

Comment: Have you tested the behaviour of the `Assembly.HostContext` property? It's of the `long` type. I peeked in that property using JustDecompile, but I still have no clue about how can its value map to those 3 categories.

Comment: I know you won't like like it :-) but you can subscribe to AppDomain.AssemblyLoad event and walk the stack (using the StackFrame class). I don't think there is any other easier way.

Comment: @SimonMourier, unfortunately, by the time my code has a chance to run, the Assembly may have already been loaded.  So, I'm looking for an "after the fact" way.  Regardless, it's not clear to me how walking the stack would help you determine what load context the assembly ended up in.

Comment: A StackTrace instance gives you a list of StackFrames, StackFrame has a GetMethod() method that can ultimately tell you if the event comes from the Assembly.LoadFrom or Load or whatever.

Comment: @SimonMourier, ah.  But as I stated in a previous comment, the Load method that is used doesn't necessarily indicate the load context where the assembly is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of identifying the context of the assembly, you could test the behavior of it. For example, for serializing, the serializer will call Assembly.Load and that assembly must *match* the assembly of the object being serialized. A match can be tested for by checking the CodeBase.

```
private static bool DoesAssemblyMatchLoad(Assembly assemblyToTest)
{
    try
    {
        var loadedAssembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyToTest.FullName);
        return assemblyToTest.CodeBase == loadedAssembly.CodeBase;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for all cases I've tried (Load,LoadFrom and LoadFile).  It has the nice feature that it will only actually Load a new assembly in the case where there is not a match.  While it doesn't technically answer the question--it does solve my problem nicely.

Answer (score 4):

- *reflection-only context*: `Assembly.ReflectionOnly == true`
- *no context* (dynamic): `Assembly.IsDynamic == true`
- *no context* (`Load(byte[])`): `Assembly.Location == null`
- *default context*: either `Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache == true` or `Assembly.Location` begins with property CodeBase
- *load-from context*: anything else assuming you would not load from from code base